# How do you make a text field automaticly add - after certain numbers

Tags: php, javascript, html

How do you make a text field automatically add - after certain numbers.

So if I was typing a date, `20120212`, it would automaticly add a - after the first 4 digits, the second two so it outputs like `2012-02-12`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PHP's `strtotime` function combined with `date`

```
$old_date = '20120212';
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($old_date)); //returns 2012-02-12
```

And after reading your question was unclear if you needed this done in PHP or JavaScript. But you can also do this with input masking in jQuery. Here is a good plugin: [**Masked Input Plugin**](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

You would format the input field like:

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("input").mask("9999-99-99");
});
```